# Let Linux host use (wireless) network driver of Windows VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization, vmware

I bought a Wifi network adapter (Asus PCE-AC88) that is not compatible with Linux - even if it works, it is very slow.
With Windows drivers, the card is extremely fast.

I'm a Linux-only user so I won't switch to Windows at all, however I'm ok (and got enough RAM) to setup a Windows VM if necessary.

I know I could setup a virtual machine with Windows 7/10 and let it use the network adapter directly via PCI passthrough, using the Windows drivers.

Now the question is - can I let the **Linux-host** access the network/Internet through the **Windows-guest** network adapter, and what are the steps to be taken?

Comment: If you want the Windows driver to control the network adapter, I'd have thought you'd want the Windows VM as the **gateway** for your Linux networking. No direct hardware mapping, just networking stuff (configure default route on Linux, configure Windows for "sharing the internet").

Comment: I too have this adapter in one of my setups and it isn't slow. Which Linux derivate do you use? I use Debian 9 by the way.

Comment: @NordlysJeger got Ubuntu 18.04. I don't have specific numbers yet, just feels not much faster than a simple low-cost wifi card. Will do some benchmarks soon

Comment: When you say 'With Windows drivers, the card is extremely fast' do you mean you use the Windows drivers in Linux with ndiswrapper and get fast performance?

Comment: @K7AAY I meant the card is fast when using native Windows. Afaik ndiswrapper doesn't work for windows7/10 drivers.

Comment: @ifischer https://sourceforge.net/p/ndiswrapper/ndiswrapper/Main_Page/  shows 64-bit Windows drivers (i.e., Windows 7/10 drivers) work OK.

Comment: Will compare patched Linux driver, ndiswrapper (thx @K7AAY), Windows VM, Windows VM + gateway (thx @dirkt) to Linux host and perform benchmarks for each setup soon

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have the same problems as the adapter is pcie, so windows is the one who manages the hardware and virtualices it to provides to the VM the network adapter. If the adapter were USB, you could map it directly to the VM.

Comment: Sorry if my question is ambiguous, but I meant running a *Windows VM* on a *Linux host*, not the other way around